# What is gunicorn app.wsgi actually doing in heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I don't quite understand how this works, and I've been searching everywhere but didn't quite find the answer. 
So when I deploy a django app on heroku the other day I was using daphne with this in the Procfile : 
`daphne app.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2`
The app works just fine and it make sense (I heard that heroku dynamically assigns the port). But how does the following code knows how to bind it's port, isn't it always 8000 by default ?

`gunicorn app.asgi`

Sorry for the silly question. I'm a newbie in devops stuff

Comment: The title of your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with the content, please update it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the port is whatever Heroku wants it to be. Since they're running many many sites, they need to dynamically choose a port to serve each one on. They provide that port in the `PORT` environment variable, and the Procfile takes that value and binds gunicorn to it.

Comment: but it doesn't specify the --bind flag, how does it know ._. ?

Comment: in the above case it does specify where to bind, is it automatic ? how does it work, in my environment setting $PORT doesn't change anything

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you specify `--port $PORT`, then it will use the environment variable PORT.

Comment: and if it doesn't what does it use ? doesn't it use the default 8000 ? how do heroku change that

Comment: I really don't understand. If the var wasn't defined, that command wouldn't work at all because it's expecting a value there. But it always will be defined on Heroku, because that's the way Heroku works.

Comment: let me elaborate more, in my procfile I wrote 
gunicorn app.wsgi  (doesn't specify any port)
so how does it bind to the port given in the $PORT ??